# Setting parameters after obtaining their values in stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Right now I have an upload field while uploads files to the server. The prefix is saved so that it can later be obtained for retrieval. For this I need to attach the ID of the form to the prefix. I would like to be able to do this as such:

```
 @filePrefix = SCOPE_IDENTITY() + @filePrefix;
```

However I am not so sure this would work because the record has not been created yet. If anything I could call an update function which obtains the ID and then injects it into the row after it has been created. To speed things up, I don't want to do this on the server but rather do this on the database.

Regardless of what the approach is, I would still like to know if something like the above is possible (at least for future reference?) So if we replace that with

```
 @filePrefix = 5 + @filePrefix;
```

would that be possible? SQL doesn't seem to like the current syntax very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could use [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) to try and predict this value I would advise against it.

If you want to set the variable try this:

```
SET @filePrefix = 5 + @filePrefix
```

I'm a bit confused by your statement `To speed things up, I don't want to do this on the server but rather do this on the database.`  What do you mean by this?

Comment: I would rather not have to call it back into the ASPX page only to call another update query

Comment: So you are saying you don't want to do this on the WEB server (the database in on a server too)?  You shouldn't need to, just select the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after you do your insert and do an update.

Comment: No the database server and the web server are two different machines, so I am trying to avoid extra latency between the two. Yes that's what I ended up doing :)